# Como saber que Protocolos TSL/SSL se estan usando en el ISS

Tags: windows-server-2012

Herede una aplicación que esta montada en el ISS de un servidor con Windows Server 2012 R2. La cuestión es que de parte de infraestructura me solicitan saber que protocolo TLS esta usando la aplicación y desconozco como averiguar esto. Estuve mirando en el ISS pero nada especifica sobre TLS.

Answer (score 1):

Hay TestSSLServer4.exe (https://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/ en inglés) que usé para determinar cuales versions de SSL o TLS supportan mis servidores y además las funciones hash que utilizan.  Es muy útil, pero no sé si hay un en español.